# Plotting a custom function that returns an array of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have my custom function in python3 as follows:

```
myFunction(A, x)
"""
Args:
A (list)
x (float)
Returns:
Y: numpy array of floats [y1,y2,...,y(len(A))]
"""
return Y
```

What I want to do is to make a plot for some chosen constant list A, where the X axis is the input argument x (ranging between some values, say 0,10) and on the Y axis are the floats in the output array (so multiple curves, in different colors)
I was thinking of doing something like this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
A = [5,10,15,20]
x = numpy.linspace(0,10,1000) #1000 numbers between 0 and 10
plt.plot(x,myFunction(A, x))
```

But I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think *"where the X axis is the input argument float (ranging between some values a,b)"* is not quite clear here. While it is of course often desireable to have an abstracted problem description, it is often much easier for others to understand when using a concrete example.

Comment: @Prune: Do you see anywhere on my question asking for code? I searched and could not find examples on how to do multiple output graphs, so I am basically asking for where to look for examples. If you don't want to help, that's fine, just keep your negative and useless comments for yourself.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I'm sorry I was not clear, let me be more specific: myFuction has arguments: (myTuple, x) where myTuple is a tuple and x is a float. The output is a numpy array where it has the form ([float1, float2, ...]). The number of floats depends on the size of the input tuple. So basically the X axis is x on the function input, and on the Y axis is the floats in the numpy array. A similar example would really help.

Comment: So say `x=8.` is your input float you want to plot on the x axes and `y=[1.,2.,1.4,2.2,0.7]` is the result of the function, you can plot `plt.plot([x]*len(y), y)`.

Comment: I rephrased my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I eventually found the way

```
x = np.linspace(0,100,1001) 
resultSet = [] #initialize list to store results


for i in range(0, len(x)): 
    resultSet.append(list(myFunction(A, x)))

resCount = len(resultSet[0]) 
labelList = [] #initialize list for legend names
for i in range(0,resCount):
    labelList.append("Line "+str(i+1))

lineObjects = plt.plot(list(x),resultSet)
plt.xlabel("x label")
plt.ylabel("y label")

plt.legend(lineObjects,labelList)
plt.show()
```